# If a bounded real-valued function $f(t)$ is discretized into $k$ values, what happens to Fourier transform $F(\omega)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fourier-analysis

Suppose there is a bounded real-valued function $f(t)$, with $t$ always a real number and can be interpreted as time.

Let $\max[f(t)] = x_k$ and $\min[f(t)] = x_1$. And let us divide $[x_1,x_k]$ into $k-1$ equal intervals, which creates $x_1,x_2,x_3,..,x_k$.

Suppose that whenever $(x_{i-1}+x_i)/2<f(t)\leq (x_i+x_{i+1})/2$, a new function $g(t) = x_i$.

In such a case, how would Fourier transform of $g(t)$ differ from $f(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we have, denoting by $A_i$ the set 
$$ A_i = f^{-1}\biggl(\left(\frac{x_{i-1} + x_i}2, \frac{x_i + x_{i+1}}2\right]\biggr) $$
that 
$$ g = \sum_{i=1}^{k} x_i \cdot \chi_{A_i} $$
This gives
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal F(g)(\tau) &= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbf R} \exp(-it\tau)g(t)\, dt\\
        &= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{i=1}^k x_i \int_{A_i} \exp(-it\tau)\, dt
\end{align*}
Comparing $\mathcal F(f)$ with $\mathcal F(g)$ gives, using that $\mathbf R = \biguplus_i A_i$ 
\begin{align*}
  \mathcal F(f)(\tau) - \mathcal F(g)(\tau) &=
     \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbf R} \exp(-it\tau)f(t)\, dt 
   - \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_i x_i \int_{A_i} \exp(-it\tau)\, dt\\
   &= \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_i \int_{A_i} \exp(-it\tau) \bigl(f(t) - x_i\bigr)\, dt
\end{align*}